# Owl-Carousel changing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

is it possible to change an image dependent on the current slide in owl carousel?
I know that there are [events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) within owl carousel but I didn't found what I wanted.

Thanks in advance to everyone who takes the time to answer the questions.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6NZy.jpg)

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div>
        <img src="image1.png"/> <!-- change to image2.png if slide 2 is active -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="owl-carousel-team">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 item">
        <h3>Slide 1</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 item">
        <h3>Slide 2</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var teamCarousel = function(){
    var owl = $('.owl-carousel-team');
    owl.owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:0,
        autoHeight:false,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1,
            },
            1000:{
                items:1,
                nav:false,
                dots: true,
            }
        }
    });
};


$(function(){
    fullHeight();
    sliderMain();
    centerBlock();
    responseHeight()
    mobileMenuOutsideClick();
    offcanvasMenu();
    burgerMenu();
    toggleBtnColor();
    contentWayPoint();
    teamCarousel();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect your slide movement by

```
owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    // Your code here
})
```

> use `translated.owl.carousel` for after slider moved

Give an id to your image tag, then get the active slider image source and set to `<img/>`

e.g.

```
owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {

    var now_src = $('.owl-carousel').find('.owl-item.active img').attr('src');

    $('#you_img_id').attr('src', now_src);
})
```

Here's the demo https://jsfiddle.net/566j4jsf/